# Is the use of this gerund correct or not?

Tags: gerunds

I'm oftenly confused with the use of gerund, both in writing and talking, like this sentence that I write to my teacher. Is the use of gerund in here correct or not?

> Sir this is the evidence of our team pasting the poster in the toilet.

Answer (score 1):

*pasting* is no gerund in your sentence because it has not the function of a noun. It's a present active participle describing what the team is/has been doing. It is/has been pasting.